# SQL query on rows with timestamp relative to another timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

New to SQL, so forgive me if this is a stupid question...

I'm attempting to count the number of rows with a timestamp in a certain range relative to **each** row in a table.

i.e.
For each row R in TableA, count the number of rows where (Timestamp) < (R.Timestamp + 1Hour) and (Foo < Bar)

```
Row     Timestamp   Foo     Bar
        (H:MM)
1       1:00        0       1
2       1:15        1       1
3       1:30        0       1
4       1:31        1       1
5       1:32        0       1
6       2:32        1       1
7       2:50        0       1
8       3:00        1       1

Row     <Query Output>
1       3
2       2
3       2
4       1
5       1
6       1
7       1
8       0
```

Is there a way to write a query to do this? performing this relative to a constant value is straight forward enough, but performing it relative to each value in a given column does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `Outer Apply` on the same table.

```
Select  A.Row, Coalesce(B.Total, 0) 
From    TableA A
Outer Apply
(
    Select  Count(*) Total
    From    TableA R
    Where   R.TimeStamp Between A.Timestamp And DateAdd(Hour, 1, A.TimeStamp)
    And     R.Foo < R.Bar
) B
```